# Python and pure virtual function error

Tags: python, win32com, pure-virtual

I wrote a GA with Python and PyEvolve. In this I used `win32com.client` to call a COM Library from another program ("Gsa.ComAuto" a program for structural engineering). For a number of generations the GA works fine but after it appears a error message. The message is R6025 Run Time Message Pure Virtual Function Call refered to gsa.exe. I don't know why this message appears maybe because I call many times the Com objects?

Comment: Have you initialized COM in your python code, with CoInitialize?

Comment: No I haven't. I put at the beginning                          import win32com.client  gsaAuto=win32com.client.Dispatch("Gsa.ComAuto")                after I call many times gsaAuto in a different definitions. Unfortunaly I don't know what is CoInitialize, can you explain it to me? Thank tou very much

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import win32com.client
win32com.client.pythoncom.CoInitialize()
```

This will [initialize your thread for using COM](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/pythoncom__CoInitialize_meth.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it tomorrow and I hope that it works. Tomorrow I'll posted the results. Thank you again.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question but I have to put win32com.client.pythoncom.CoInitialize()  in every definition that uses the COM object or just in the main definition?

Comment: You need to call it for any thread, just once. So, usually at the top of the module is OK, but if you're making your own threads, they need to initialize early on as well.